# Изменить вывод даты из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Сделала себе таблицу, в которой помечаю, когда заменяла наполнитель котам. К сожалению, знаний по PHP и MySQL нет, просто исопльзую куски кода, которые удаётся нагуглить. Премного обяжете, если исправите этот код так, чтобы дата выводилась день-месяц-год, а не наоборот. Спасибо.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$con_str=mysql_connect('sql208.byethost22.com', 'b22_20575378', 'SFag234a', 'b22_20575378_sand');
if(mysql_connect('sql208.byethost22.com','b22_20575378')){
echo "Hello!!!";
}
mysql_select_db('b22_20575378_sand',$con_str); 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `b22_20575378_sand`.`sand`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$id=$row['id'];
$date=$row['date'];
$some=$row['some']; 
echo "<p>$date</p>";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime($row['date']);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

Виды форматирования можно посмотреть в документации: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php

---

На самом деле для этой цели сам php не нужен. Можно это сделать средствами БД:

```
DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15", "%d-%m-%Y") as `date`
```

Список возможных параметров форматирования указан тут: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Comment: Вот первый вариант, средствами php подошёл. Второй находила в сети, но сделать так у себя не получилось. Спасибо.

Comment: Потому что это требует прописывания столбцов вручную, желательно без `*` типа `SELECT some,  DATE_FORMAT(\`date\`, "%d-%m-%Y") as \`date\` FROM ....`

Comment: Если ответ помог - галочку тык %)

Answer (score 2):

Варианты:

1. Смена формата на стороне базы и получение как "date2"

```php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') as date2 FROM `b22_20575378_sand`.`sand`");
```

И тогда соответственно заменить

```php
$date=$row['date'];
```

на

```php
$date=$row['date2'];
```

2. Смена формата на стороне PHP

```php
$date=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['date']));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас проблема решена, но будет полезно на будущее.